# Drawing multiple Circles to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am trying to plot multiple points on Google maps as circles. The points represent traffic monitoring stations that count the volume of traffic. I'd like to plot bigger circles to represent a bigger volume of traffic.

Here is the page that is trying to create circles-
 http://clecomdev.org/View_TrafficCounts.php
Here is the page that shows all traffic stations as pins- http://www.clecomdev.org/ERR/ALL_TrafficStations.php

I can plot all the locations as pins, but converting the pins to circles with a radius that is relative to their traffic volume won't show. The code below has a fixed radius until I can get the circles to show.

```
<script>
    var myMapTraffic;
    var myLatlngTraffic = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>,<?php echo $longitude; ?>);
    var markersTraffic = <?php echo json_encode(array_values($TrafficWithin12Mile));?>;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: myLatlngTraffic,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  ,
            scrollwheel: false
        }
        myMapTraffic = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapTraffic'), mapOptions);
    var circleTraffic;
    var markersTraffic;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < markersTraffic.length; i++) {
        var positionTraffic = new google.maps.LatLng(markersTraffic[i][3], markersTraffic[i][4]);
        circleTraffic = new google.maps.Circle({
           map : myMapTraffic,
           radius: 1000,    
           fillColor: "#ff0000",
        });
        circleTraffic.bindTo('center', positionTraffic, 'position')
        };

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Tried the following change to plotting a circle, but no luck:

```
var markersTraffic;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < markersTraffic.length; i++) {
        var circleTraffic = new google.maps.Circle({
           map : myMapTraffic,
           center: {lat: markersTraffic[i][3], lng: markersTraffic[i][4]},
           radius: 1000,    
           fillColor: "#ff0000",
        });

        };
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `center` property to the Circle options instead of using `bindTo`?

Comment: What errors do you get when "they won't show"?  I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` with the posted code.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to a broken page.

Comment: I just tried, but no luck, but I could be doing wrong. Tried center: positionTraffic,

Comment: The map won't show, php is printing the table correctly. See links to see one that works with pins and the one that is being worked on for circles.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip. I worked through the errors, so now the map shows. But I still can't get the circles to show.

Comment: Edited the code about to reflect the minor changes.

Comment: Error I get is "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at initialize" ?

Comment: Have you looked at [the example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Here is the answer.

```
<script>
    var myMapTraffic;
    var myLatlngTraffic = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>,<?php echo $longitude; ?>);
    var markersTraffic = <?php echo json_encode(array_values($TrafficWithin12Mile));?>;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: myLatlngTraffic,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  ,
            scrollwheel: false
        }
        myMapTraffic = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapTraffic'), mapOptions);

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < markersTraffic.length; i++) {
        var positionTraffic = new google.maps.LatLng(markersTraffic[i][3], markersTraffic[i][4]);
        var circleTraffic = new google.maps.Circle({
           map : myMapTraffic,
           center: positionTraffic,
           radius: Math.sqrt(Number(markersTraffic[i][1])),    
           fillColor: "#ff0000",
        });

        };

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```